# How to analyze javascript control flow of a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can you suggest a tool or script which can help me analyze javascript control flow of a third party website ?

Comment: F12 opens chromes developer tools. From Sources tab you can open your desired javascript, set up a breakpoint and step through the code as it executes. Or you would like something more advanced?

Answer (score 0):

you can place breakpoints in Google chrome, this may help you that how the flow is going on.see the below available link

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Just press F12 on chrome.